Using impersonation from External Script?
We're on SQL Server 2022, and want to use Impersonation when accessing another (remote) SQL Server from our Python code (our external script).
I.e., the security credentials on the remote SQL Server should be windows account that logon to the SQL server where the external script is executed from.
I understand that the Launchpad service is used to execute a script and we possibly can start the Launchpad server as a domain account, and create a login on the remote server for that domain account. But that means that all logins on the local server will use the same credentials on the remote SQL Server.
